# Regex - Count number of uppercase letters in word

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I would like to find all words in a text that have more than one uppercase letter.
So far, I am checking only if the last character is uppercase

```
\b.*[A-Z]\b
```

but it would be more precise if I had the condition that the last letter or in total two characters in the word are uppercase.

Comment: Use `\b(?:\w*[A-Z]){2}\w*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?:[a-z]*[A-Z]){2}[a-zA-Z]*\b', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yq2l05/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:[a-z]*[A-Z]){2}` - two sequences of zero or more lowercase letters followed with an uppercase letter
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RL9m1y):

```py
import re
text = "A VeRy LoNG SenTence Here"
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:[a-z]*[A-Z]){2}[a-zA-Z]*\b', text))
# => ['VeRy', 'LoNG', 'SenTence']
```

A fully Unicode-aware regex is possible with the [PyPi `regex` library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (install in your terminal/console with `pip install regex`):

```py
import regex
text = "Да, ЭтО ОченЬ ДЛинное предложение."
print(regex.findall(r'\b(?:\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}){2}\p{L}*\b', text))
# => ['ЭтО', 'ОченЬ', 'ДЛинное']
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsktaJEwVZB6cKUCxt0FC6svdh0YZ7ChXkX2y9svbD3whoFoPjsCzuAzL0X9l3YqnBh/8UGoMyWC7uB3G1gNTsubNVT4iooyswr0QCbqZeWmZeSmJOjUaQek6RhbxVTUO2TU6sFokprNauNakEsID9JXUcBZL2m5v//AA).

Comment: FYI: `\p{Ll}` - any Unicode lowercase letter, `\p{Lu}` - any Unicode uppercase letter and `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

Answer (score 0):

\b(\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*|.*[A-Z])\b

explanation: this will match either, any word with upper case at the end (your regex has been reused here) - OR - a string of zero or more word chars (\w), followed by a single uppercase, followed by a string of zero or more word chars (\w), followed by a single uppercase and finally another zero or more word chars.
The \w is shorthand for [A-Za-z0-9_]